# What could be possible ways to make users renew their plan on mobile app

Tags: interaction-design, user-behavior, design-patterns, user-research, accessibility

We have an application where users have to subscribe to health plans for 3,6,or 12 months. Once the subscription is about to expire we need to send, remind and prompt users to renew their subscription.

What are possible ways to show users on the home screen that they have to renew their subscription in an intuitive way?

Comment: Can you provide mockups of what your application looks like and what you have tried so far?

Comment: As it stands, this question is incredibly broad. Adding some screenshots or mockups would help us to narrow down on what would be useful in your particular use-case

Comment: Make your users addicted to your product then you don't need to remind them, when it expires and they find they can't use it they will renew straight away ;)

Comment: Here is the link to the homescreen where we need a way to show the renewal option which has to be there persistently.                                                     https://goo.gl/photos/Sup3hXY9bQ31VyaM6

Answer (score 2):

The most important information for the use case you describe are the following:

- **How much time is left**. Display a message showing how much time is left until the subscription expires. Use the word "only" when less than 10 days are left to stress the urgency of the issue  i.e. "*only 3 days left on your subscription*". Also, use big fonts and high contrast that will progressively increase, as the days become less, to attract users attention.
- **How to renew the subscription**. Add a link/button next to the above message that will take the user to a renewal page, with renewal information and instructions. The link/button text could be something like "Renew Subscription". Make it clear that the text is clickable by using blue color and underline, or a button.

The above apply whether you send an email or display a message in the home screen of the user.